# Vue.js - Prism code is not shown from a computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

For the purpose of learning Vue, I am trying to create a very simple app that will return highlighted code from the input in real-time. I went through a few Prism tutorials and examples, but can't get this to work. Any help or guidance will be appreciated, as I am just getting started with Vue and I have a feeling that I am mixing something up.

This is `HelloWorld.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Prism Demo</h1>
    <div id="editor">
      <textarea v-model="message"></textarea>
      <div>{{ highlighteddMessage }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Prism from 'vue-prism-component'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: `var myFunction = function() {
    statements
}`
};
  },
      computed: {
        highlighteddMessage: function () {
        return Prism.highlight(this.message, Prism.languages.js);
      }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
...
</style>
```

And my `main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import "prismjs";
import "prismjs/themes/prism-funky.css";
import "prismjs/components/prism-scss.min";
import "prismjs/plugins/autolinker/prism-autolinker.min";
import "prismjs/plugins/autolinker/prism-autolinker.css";
import Prism from "vue-prism-component";
Vue.component("prism", Prism);

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

I think the problem is in how I am trying to use Prism in the computed property, but I am unable to fix it. WIll appreciate any hints on correctly using Prism in Vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `Prism` to your components option `components:{Prism}` and then in the template wrap the code with that component and no need to create a computed property :

```
  <div>
    <h1>Prism Demo</h1>
    <div id="editor">
      <textarea v-model="message"></textarea>


  <prism language="javascript">{{ message  }}</prism>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Prism from 'vue-prism-component'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: `var myFunction = function() {
    statements
}`
};
  },
  components:{
     Prism
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! And if I would like to use the Excel plugin instead of js, do you know how to include it? I tried the following, but no luck: https://github.com/mAAdhaTTah/babel-plugin-prismjs

Comment: you want to highlight excel data?

Comment: It's this one here that I would like to use: `Excel Formula - excel-formula, xlsx, xls` https://prismjs.com/

Comment: did you try ` <prism language="xls">{{ message  }}</prism>`

Comment: yes, but getting this error: `vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 Error: Prism component for language "xls" was not found, did you forget to register it? See all available ones: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/prismjs/components/`

Comment: in the given link in `excel-formula` exists , so try `<prism language="excel-formula">{{ message }}</prism>`

Comment: yeah, tried that as well and now it says `vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 Error: Prism component for language "excel-formula" was not found, did you forget to register it? See all available ones: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/prismjs/components/` - shouldn't I install it somewhere first? and what does it mean "to register"? Sorry, I am brand new to all of this and not sure how to navigate all those plugins

Comment: it's weird it should be supported